Pulse Audio - Docker Fargate Container (XVFB FFEMPEG Selenium)
i'm having some issues about pulse audio, in my local enviroment windows using docker image i can deploy a application that can open a browser using selenium (this works fine) and capture the audio using pulse audio - MySync.monitor, transfer to ffmpeg all this running inside docker container locally.
but im try to put on fargate container and im struggle because all the process work fine, the start and recording..but when i open the file not have audio browser, but locally have.
do you guys have some config about pulse-audio that can run on fargate task container correctly ? i can send the file after recording finished to s3, and this file have size all good but when i open the audio captured from browser like youtube not play, audio is silence.
I appreciate some help! thank you!
def start_ffmpeg(audio_only: bool):

 # Carregar o módulo null-sink
start_pulse_audio()

"""Inicia o processo do FFmpeg."""
command = [
    "ffmpeg",
    "-threads", "4",
    "-f", "pulse",
    "-i", "MySink.monitor",
    "-c:a", "libmp3lame" if audio_only else "aac",
    "-b:a", "128k",
    "-y",
    "/tmp/audio.mp3" if audio_only else "/tmp/video.mp4",
    "-loglevel", "debug"
]
if not audio_only:
    command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-threads", "4",
        "-thread_queue_size", "4096",  # Aumenta a fila de mensagens
        "-probesize", "10M",  # Aumenta o buffer de detecção
        "-f", "x11grab",  # Captura a tela no Linux
        "-framerate", "30",  # Define taxa de quadros constante
        "-video_size", "1920x1080",  # Configura tamanho da área de captura
        "-i", ":99",  # Display virtual criado pelo Xvfb
        "-f", "pulse",  # Captura de áudio via PulseAudio
        "-i", "MySink.monitor",  # Dispositivo de áudio configurado no PulseAudio
        "-c:v", "libx264",  # Codec de vídeo
        "-crf", "23",  # Taxa de compressão equilibrada (menor = melhor qualidade)
        "-preset", "ultrafast",  # Processamento rápido
        "-c:a", "libmp3lame",  # Codec de áudio
        "-b:a", "128k",  # Qualidade do áudio
        "-shortest",  # Finaliza o vídeo quando o áudio termina
        "-y",  # Sobrescrever o arquivo de saída
        "/tmp/video.mp4",
        "-loglevel", "debug"
    ]
try:
    logging.info(f"Iniciando FFmpeg com o comando: {' '.join(command)}")
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    threading.Thread(target=log_ffmpeg_output, args=(process,), daemon=True).start()
    return process
except Exception as e:
    logging.info(f"Erro ao iniciar o FFmpeg: {e}")
    return None

def start_pulse_audio():
try:
    logging.info("Verificando fontes disponíveis do PulseAudio...")
    result = subprocess.run(["pactl", "list", "sources", "short"], text=True, capture_output=True)
    
    if result.returncode != 0 or "MySink.monitor" not in result.stdout:
        logging.info("PulseAudio ou MySink.monitor não configurados. Tentando corrigir...")
        subprocess.run(["pulseaudio", "--kill"], check=False)
        subprocess.run(["pulseaudio", "--start"], check=True)
        subprocess.run(["pactl", "load-module", "module-null-sink", "sink_name=MySink"], check=True)
        logging.info("MySink configurado com sucesso!")
    
    # Verificar se o monitor está ativo
    monitor_state = subprocess.run(["pactl", "list", "sources"], text=True, capture_output=True)
    if "RUNNING" not in monitor_state.stdout:
        logging.warning("MySink.monitor está IDLE. Reproduzindo tom contínuo para ativar...")
        # Gerar tom contínuo artificial
        subprocess.Popen([
            "ffmpeg", "-f", "lavfi", "-i", "sine=frequency=1000:duration=10", "-f", "pulse", "MySink"
        ])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    logging.error(f"Erro ao configurar o PulseAudio: {e.stderr}")
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"Erro ao verificar ou configurar o PulseAudio: {e}")




2024-11-24T11:02:46.552-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,552 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.552-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,552 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.552-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,552 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [rawvideo @ 0x55a87452a780] PACKET SIZE: 8294400, STRIDE: 7680
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.559-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,559 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.559-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,559 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.560-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,560 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [rawvideo @ 0x55a87452a780] PACKET SIZE: 8294400, STRIDE: 7680
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.565-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,564 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: *** 58 dup!
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.596-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,595 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40] frame= 0 QP=20.00 NAL=3 Slice:I Poc:0 I:8160 P:0 SKIP:0 size=41730 bytes
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.597-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,597 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40] frame= 1 QP=19.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:2 I:0 P:89 SKIP:8071 size=445 bytes
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.605-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,604 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40] frame= 2 QP=17.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:4 I:161 P:340 SKIP:7659 size=4891 bytes
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.608-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,608 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40] frame= 3 QP=15.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:6 I:18 P:451 SKIP:7691 size=8614 bytes
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.609-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,609 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40] frame= 4 QP=14.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:8 I:49 P:376 SKIP:7735 size=3955 bytes
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.614-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,614 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40] frame= 5 QP=14.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:10 I:0 P:5 SKIP:8155 size=44 bytes
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.614-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,614 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40] frame= 6 QP=13.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:12 I:71 P:382 SKIP:7707 size=6724 bytes
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.617-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,617 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40] frame= 7 QP=13.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:14 I:0 P:15 SKIP:8145 size=125 bytes
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.618-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,618 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40] frame= 8 QP=13.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:16 I:0 P:0 SKIP:8160 size=12 bytes
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.620-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,620 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40] frame= 9 QP=13.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:18 I:0 P:0 SKIP:8160 size=12 bytes
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.623-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,623 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40] frame= 10 QP=13.00 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:20 I:0 P:0 SKIP:8160 size=12 bytes
Link 


2024-11-24T11:02:46.628-03:00
2024-11-24 14:02:46,628 [ERROR] FFmpeg STDERR: [libx264 @ 0x55a874538e40]

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
